# Google chrome 42 + Rails with Devise + User Not able to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, session, cookies, devise

Every time google chrome comes with a new version it breaks something very badly and then how we can explain to users? Do they trust, that "The google" can do this?

Anyways, here is the issue.

Browser - Chrome 42.0.2311.90 m

Issue - Rails site, with Devise gem, is working fine in FF, Safari and old versions (tested on 41.0.2272.118) of chrome. But, does not work with the above mentioned version and user is not able to login into the system.

This has been verified on all other browsers, also checked that there are no code changes which can do this.

Any help would be great, this really is annoying because i am sitting for this since last 5 hours just checking the google chrome settings for cookies.

Comment: Still this issue is not resolved, as there are no concrete issues found. As of now, we need to clear the cache whenever we face it.

Comment: I have a similar problem. It started with first user reports about random logouts or not being able to log in two weeks ago.

Clearing cookies in Chrome helps temporarily – until the application accesses the cookie store the next time (then there is no session and the application redirects to the login form again).

This is very strange and very frustrating for my users. Does anyone know a solution?